# Change json array response to int array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm having a lot of troubles to get the data from thingspeak into a json response. I have a url and the response of that give me a many fields. This is the response of the JSON:

```
?({"channel":{"id":XXXXX,"name":"XXXXX","field1":"Temperature","field2":"Humidity","created_at":"2015-11-03T13:12:06Z","updated_at":"2015-11-15T12:07:37Z","last_entry_id":142},"feeds":[{"created_at":"2015-11-14T21:06:16Z","entry_id":136,"field1":"0"},{"created_at":"2015-11-14T21:06:39Z","entry_id":137,"field1":"25"},{"created_at":"2015-11-14T21:06:59Z","entry_id":138,"field1":"24.05"},{"created_at":"2015-11-14T21:07:13Z","entry_id":139,"field1":"24.45"},{"created_at":"2015-11-14T21:08:16Z","entry_id":140,"field1":"24.45"},{"created_at":"2015-11-15T12:06:18Z","entry_id":141,"field1":"24.5"},{"created_at":"2015-11-15T12:07:37Z","entry_id":142,"field1":"21.4"}]})
```

I want to retrieve the maximum and minimum value of each field1 data. I have been reading and the response is not in int, therefore should be converted to an int array.

This is my code at the moment:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/'+channel+'/field/1.json?callback=?',
                {key: read_API_key, days: "1"},
                function(data) {
                    $.each(data.feeds, function() {
                        var temp_vals = this.field1;
                        var temp_vals_date = this.created_at;
                        console.log(temp_vals);
                    });
                }
            );
```

I want to search inside feed array looking for the field1 numbers and save into an int array to after do the maths using `Math.max.apply(Math, temp_vals);` Using the console, the values are saved correctly into `temp_vals`, but I cannot use that function, with the following error: `Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type`.

Therefore, how can I change the response into a int array or something to be able to find the max and min value? And another quick question, is any way to print the values outside of the $.each(data.feeds,function(){});, because I didn't find a way to do it....

**Changing to parseInt:**

```
$.getJSON('http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/'+channel+'/field/1.json?callback=?',
                {key: read_API_key, days: "1"},
                function(data) {
                    $.each(data.feeds, function() {
                        var temp_vals = parseInt(this.field1);
                        var temp_vals_date = this.created_at;
                        var temp_max = Math.max.apply(Math, temp_vals);
                        console.log(temp_max);

                        $('#temp1_max').text(temp_max + ' ºC');

                        console.log(temp_vals);
                    });
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parseInt`

```
var temp_vals = parseInt( this.field1 );
```

Edit:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/'+channel+'/field/1.json?callback=?',
                {key: read_API_key, days: "1"},
                function(data) {
                 var temp_vals = [];
                    $.each(data.feeds, function() {
                        temp_vals.push( parseInt( this.field1 ) );
                        var temp_vals_date = this.created_at;
                    });
                     var temp_max = Math.max.apply(Math, temp_vals);
                     console.log(temp_max);
                     console.log(temp_vals);
                     $('#temp1_max').text(temp_max + ' ºC');
                }
            );
```

Comment: I still have the same problem when do the math function...I think the problem is not with the int

Comment: Maybe because `var temp_vals` is redefining the variable for every `data.feeds` entry. Define it outside AJAX request and then push the result into it like: `temp_vals.push( parseInt( this.field1 ) );`

Comment: It says: `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`, and the log does not show anything. So I do not know if I am receiving some value. I am going to check again to solve this.

Comment: Without using push it works and show all the values inside the console log, but when I tried to do the math function it doesn't work...

Comment: I have edited the answer with some code changes. Should work now.